# LaTeX template for Lecture notes

Tags: packages, document-classes, presentations

Looking for some good templates for creating lecture notes to be given to students.

Mainly for computer science subjects. More frequently need short lecture notes.

Comment: Could you please be more specific. What kind of lecture notes (complete text or just an outline)? What subject?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know that the [`beamer` documentclass](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) provides some information on "Splitting a Course Into Lectures" (see Section 9.4 on p 81 of the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)) by means of the command `\lecture`. From the package documentation:

> When using beamer with the article mode, you may wish to have the
>   lecture notes of a whole course reside in one file. In this case, only
>   a few frames are actually part of any particular lecture.
>
> The `\lecture` command makes it easy to select only a certain set of
>   frames from a file to be presented. This command takes (among other
>   things) a label name. If you say `\includeonlylecture` with this label
>   name, then only the frames following the corresponding `\lecture`
>   command are shown. The frames following other `\lecture` commands are
>   suppressed.
>
> By default, the `\lecture` command has no other effect. It does not
>   create any frames or introduce entries in the table of contents.
>   However, you can use `\AtBeginLecture` to have BEAMER insert, say, a
>   title page at the beginning of (each) lecture.

It also provides you with the means to produce "handouts" of your lectures via the documentclass option

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
```

On "Creating the Handout", the package documentation mentions:

> Once your talk is fixed, you can create a handout, if this seems
>   appropriate. For this, you can use the class option `handout` as
>   explained in Section 21.1. Typically, you might wish to put several
>   handout slides on one page, see below on how to do this easily.
>
> You may also wish to create an article version of your talk. An
>   "article version" of your presentation is a normal TeX text typeset
>   using, for example, the document class `article` or perhaps `llncs` or
>   a similar document class. The BEAMER class offers facilities to have
>   this version coexist with your presentation version in one file and to
>   share code. Also, you can include slides of your presentation as
>   figures in your article version. Details on how to setup the article
>   version can be found in Section 21.2.

If your interested in following an example of how to set up a presentation/lecture using `beamer`, consider the bed-time reading of [Beamer by Example](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-4/mertz/mertz.pdf) by Andrew Mertz & William Slough - part of PracTeX Journal 2005, no 4.

---

In addition to the above suggested reading, [Googling for 'beamer templates'](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=beamer+templates) leads to some links that will give you a good feel for what `beamer` can do, and get you started:

- [A Ready-made Beamer Presentation Template](http://www.stattler.com/article/ready-made-beamer-presentation-template)
- [A Beamer Tutorial in Beamer](http://www.uncg.edu/cmp/reu/presentations/Charles%20Batts%20-%20Beamer%20Tutorial.pdf)
- [Simple Beamer Template for Getting Started and Reducing Typing](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2010/08/simple-beamer-template-for-getting.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently come across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOtM1mrWjUo&t=681s) *"How I take notes as a Math major using Vim + LaTeX"* by Gilles Castel. He also elaborated on detailed [blog](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/). I feel the template given by the author is very beautiful. Sadly, it's mentioned in a [comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOtM1mrWjUo&lc=UgyBCHtOu_8blA9Bj894AaABAg) below the video that he has passed away. I would like to share his contribution so that many people can benefit from it. Please download his template from [here](https://github.com/SeniorMars/dotfiles/tree/master/latex_template).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use my [willowtreebook](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.4172.1632943714.2581.ctan-ann@ctan.org) class. It is drawn from the memoir class, but with a simpler interface and automatic selection of my favourite defaults for the memoir class. For example, it colour code chapters automatically. You can see my lecture notes on my [web page](https://ben-mckay.github.io/benmckay.github.io/).

You might also look at [Best LaTeX Templates for books and lecture notes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94970/best-latex-templates-for-books-and-lecture-notes/94972#94972)