# Best LaTeX Templates for books and lecture notes

Tags: math-mode, indexing, templates, appendices, book-design

I have written and submitted a lectures series in mathematics in arXiv, arXiv:1211.3404. Its format is book, but I have some difficulties with it. For example for page numbering, indexing, etc. I am going to extend my lecture notes in the form of a relatively long book, so I need to choose a better template for my work.

I am looking for an easy to use and perfect book template in Latex. I need a template that allows indexing, adding appendices, different page numbering for introduction and content, different numbering for exercises.

It is also favorable if the template (preferably) does not use so many user packages.

Comment: I think you can look at [Showcase of beautiful typography done in tex friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends) where you will goog book examples. But if you don't want to use "many user packages", I'd suggest [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class because it integrates several packages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use my own [easy template](https://ctan.org/pkg/willowtreebook) for the [memoir class](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf) for my lecture notes. For more easy templates, take a look at [a painless template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70824/painless-memoir-class-book-template) for the memoir class.

You can see some of my lectures notes in [algebra](https://github.com/Ben-McKay/concrete-algebra/blob/master/algebra.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

I am answering this question nearly 5 years after it was posted because a Google search brought me here as I am preparing some notes for a mathematical lecture course - and I wanted to add a couple of suggestions.

For most lecture courses I use [revtex](https://journals.aps.org/revtex) of the APS and produce notes with two columns on A4 paper a bit like APS journals e.g. Phys. Rev. Lett. (ok they use Letter paper size, but revtex works nicely for A4 and Letter).  I have been happy with the quality and general ease of using revtex, but there have been a couple of small things that mean for the maths notes I am looking elsewhere. One example is putting boxes around things such as equations, which may be possible, but I have not been able to figure out in revtex - so it may not be possible - or at least does not seem to be easy.

I have not done this yet, but my plan is to use [amslatex](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex) - amslatex is provided by the American Mathematical Society for journals and books with lots of maths, so it seems a natural choice...

Comment: It seems to me that you lack a basic understanding of how LaTeX works, and what classes and packages are. You can use `amsmath` with revtex as well.

Comment: @Johannes_B - ok fair enough - I am not a Latex guru, but I do know that you would generally use one class in Latex and that you can add whichever multiple packages you need,.... So I was talking about using ams classes instead of revtek... rather than just adding amsmath